# click event triggering on input type="file" is not working

Tags: javascript

/note: this only applies when used on the specified domain,  but works practically/

I've been trying to simulate a mouse click event, it works for anything else but not for this..

I tested it, it is working now somehow.. but whenever I try to run on this website: http://www.multiplayerpiano.com/ it seems not to work...

```
<input type="file" id="_LOAD" accept="mp3" />

$('#_LOAD').click();
```

this doesn't work..

I've also tried

```
$('#_LOAD')[0].click();
```

no luck..

can anyone please explain what is it that is blocking it on That specific domain?

// edit - original code

I was trying to make a function which will allow me to make file dialog box's which only allows a specific mime type to be allowed

```
var load = function(mime,callback){

    var tempmime = (mime) ? mime : "";

    var tempinp = $('<input style="position:absolute;opacity:0;z-index:-1;pointer-events:none" type="file" id="_LOAD" ' + (tempmime == "" ? "" : 'accept=".' + tempmime + '"') + '/>')

    $("body").append(tempinp);
    $(tempinp).focus().click();
// 
    var aab = function(msg){
    callback(msg);
         $(tempinp).off('change',aab);
        $(tempinp).remove();
    };
    $(tempinp).on('change',aab);
}
```

So this is as far i have got without .click working.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" ?

Comment: It is not triggering the click event.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nxzsqdho/1/ - I think the browser is blocking the default behavior if the click is triggered from a non user initated method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

Answer (score 2):

can you try

```
  $("#_LOAD").trigger('click');
```

Comment: can you try with variable name like $(tempinp).trigger('click');

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
document.getElementById("_LOAD").click();
```

Also you can check if you are selecting elements with

```
console.log("Element exists : " + (document.getElementById("_LOAD") != null ) );
```

Comment: `document.getElementById()` returns a unique element. Also, the `<input>` element as no `length` property.