# Cant open file dialog with button inside label

Tags: css, html

To hide (but retain the functionality) the ugly default input type file button for file dialog I used the following mechanism:

**HTML:**

```
    <label for="file-input">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <!-- acts as file input on click-->
    </label>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" />
```

**CSS:**

```
#file-input {
    display: none; //hide the file input
}
```

This is working expectedly: I click on the font awesome edit icon and the file dialog pops up.

However, when I use a button it stops working. I get no file dialog on clicking the button:

```
    <label for="file-input">
        <button type="button">Upload file</button> <!-- not working-->
    </label>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Label represents a "caption" for an item in a user interface.
The reason why your button isn't working is because a button isn't considered a valid "caption" for a "control" element because it is a "control" element.
(see: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

If you use an image or a piece of text inside the label it will work, because that will be considered a caption (this is why your first attempt worked). If you want to create a custom button you can use some text or an image tag otherwise you'll need some javascript.

Edit: maybe this page can be of help: http://webmuch.com/how-to-customize-a-file-upload-button-using-css3-html5-and-javascript/
The javascript they use shows the user what file (s)he has selected

Answer (score -2):

Just change the jQuery code and HTML tag will be as it is.

```
    <label for="file-input">
        <button class="upload_file" type="button">Upload file</button> <!-- not working-->
    </label>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" />
```

Jquery Code:

```
jquery("[for=file-input] .upload_file").on("click", function(){
    jQuery("#file-input").trigger("click");
})
```

Comment: I dont want an icon inside my button. Adding 'fa fa-edit' adds an edit icon.

Comment: I am not using jquery and this is not related to javascript in any way.

Comment: but there is some code of jquery on that fa-edit icon that will triger the file inbox

Comment: click doesn't mean jquery. Its an input type file. If you click on an input type file, a file dialog opens.

Comment: but not click on input type file button,
You clicked on that icon and that will trigger the input type file click.

Comment: Yes and that trigger happens using label's 'for' attribute.

Comment: I am not using jquery in my project!

Comment: then use $ instead of jQuery

Comment: This method doesn't work. You cannot programmatically click an input[type=file] element, for security reasons.

Comment: @kevin There is not any security issue with it and we are using these option commonly.

Comment: If you just want to down vote then I have no issue :)

Comment: @HarshSanghani Triggering click simply on an input file element doesn't work in all browsers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

But I'm not sure about the click triggered by another click event. Please edit the answer so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @kevin My answer was perfect for me and many others I don't want to change it.