# HTML button inside label doesn't trigger file upload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use the label for trick to create custom file input:

```css
    input[type="file"] {
        width: 0.1px;
        height: 0.1px;
        opacity: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
    section {
     padding: 30px;
     border: 1px solid lightgray;
     width: 200px;
     margin: 100px;
    }
    
    label {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <section>
     <label for="test">
         <input type="file" id="test">
         <button>Click me</button>
        </label>
    </section>
```

But when I click the button inside the label it doesn't not open the file popup, only when I click outside it's working. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have some javascript that makes the button trigger the file input? Just putting a button next to it won't do anything.

Comment: You should not nest multiple interactive elements into a label element to begin with - that is invalid HTML. This should not be a `button` element here in the first place. If you need certain parts of the label content to _look like_ a button, then wrap that part into a span or something, and format it accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant open file dialog with button inside label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543353/cant-open-file-dialog-with-button-inside-label)

Answer (score 2):

```
<section>
    <label for="test">
      <input type="file" id="test">
      <button onclick="document.querySelector('#test').click()">Click me</button>
 </label>
</section>
```

You can trigger a click Event on your button that simulates a click on the input

Answer (score 1):

Input should be in the front of button element and set the with as the width of button.

See the snippet, I made some change.

```css
  input[type="file"] {
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 61px;
  }

section {
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 100px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <label for="test">
      <input type="file" id="test">
      <button>Click me</button>
 </label>
</section>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543353/cant-open-file-dialog-with-button-inside-label

Comment: Related question but different answer, this one nails it. More straightforward than the accepted answer mentioned in the link given by Alexander_F.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `label` inside the `button` tag and try it.

Be sure to reset the `button` padding and give styles to the `label` tag.

```css
input[type="file"] {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

button {
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 100px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 1px 7px 2px;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <input type="file" id="test">
  <button><label for="test">Click me</label></button>

</section>
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/fywo3t18/1/)

Comment: label inside of button is invalid HTML.

Comment: Yes. but it works if not validated.
Also, Button inside label is not a good practice IMHO.