# on Window.onload form is not loading

Tags: javascript, window.onunload

on Window.onload form is not loading
My code is :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload=formOnWindowLoad();
function formOnWindowLoad(){
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('fileUploadForm');},3000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<br>Select a file to upload: <br />
<form id="fileUploadForm" action="fileLocalUpload.htm?eId=${eId}&tId=${tId}" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input id="uploadFileOnRemoteServer" type="file" name="uploadingFile" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

I want file select box on window onload

Comment: what do you need? Do you want the file field open on window.load

Comment: Yes, You right. I  want the file field open on window.load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is working, but you are not doing anything with that function. You are just getting the elemant thats it.

If you want to open the file upload after some interval, this code works for you. I have kept an alert for your understanding.

```js
window.onload=formOnWindowLoad();
function formOnWindowLoad(){
 setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById('uploadFileOnRemoteServer').click()},500);
}
```

```html
<br>Select a file to upload: <br />
<form id="fileUploadForm" action="fileLocalUpload.htm?eId=${eId}&tId=${tId}" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input id="uploadFileOnRemoteServer" type="file" name="uploadingFile" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
  
</form>
```

This works for you.If that is your requirement.It will open after 3 seconds.

[Go through this link...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)

Comment: alert box is getting but open file dialog box is not opening

Comment: I will reduce the time.wait. Remove alert reduce the time interveal to 500 and check.

Comment: Yes, its working with IE bot not working with other browser

Comment: try with jquery, $('document').ready(function() { } ), wait I will update the ans

Comment: Working with IE only

Comment: [Go through this answer..There is a problem with file field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input/210652#210652)

Comment: got it. but if there are another way please write here

Comment: Sure. :-) I will do.