# echo variable and select it

Tags: php, html, variables, echo

i'm trying to echo a variable to a search box to be the placeholder and the value
the search box will search on google maps.

the variable is $address

```
$address = $_SESSION['mylocation']['address'];
```

and then in html i've this form

```
<input name="custom[map_location]" id="form_map_location" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $address ?>" value="<?php  echo $address ?>">
```

the variable echos fine, but to really choose the value echoed and change the location to the echod value i've to click inside the text form box and then click away, then it detects the location, i need to do this automatically without clicking inside the form

i've added a chunk of the code that loads the map
http://pastebin.com/XMZiXwiW

Comment: Sounds like there is a JS event for `onclick`, or `blur`. That PHP looks right.

Comment: here's some js answers for firing the click event: http://stackoverflow.com/q/210643/4233593

Comment: Where is your `google.maps` JavaScript code? If you're using database or Session information, why not use AJAX with `google.maps` JavaScript API?

Comment: Also did you really leave off the closing `>` or is that a pasting mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the variable in the input to the JavaScript function via the on change event?

If you are you may need to create two listeners
1. "Change event" to capture new values that get put in the input field
2. "Document Ready event" to grab the value you are passing via PHP and use it when building the map.

Not sure if this is how you are going about things but hopefully it helps.  If I am off base here, can you share more of your work so I can see how your initiating the map and updating it.

Comment: i don't know what you really need, but here is a big snippet of the php file that loads the map http://pastebin.com/XMZiXwiW

Comment: Jim - this is your first answer so, i guess, you're not very familiar with the markdown syntax.  It is worth learning to make more appealing answers.  Also, do not be afraid of making very long answers.  For example, if you could give an example snippet of both listeners you're mentioning your answer would be much better.

Comment: Looking at how much there is going on I would start out with the basics and add back a piece at a time.  Make sure that the variables you need are being captured properly and  then go from there.  I simplified your page down to the bare minimum so that I could ensure I was getting the value of the #form_map_location element.

Comment: <?php $address = '123 Address City, ST 12345'; ?>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="showmapbox">
        <input name="custom[map_location]" id="form_map_location" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $address ?>" value="<?php  echo $address /*echo get_post_meta($_GET['eid'],'map_location',true)*/?>"  />
</div>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
                var location = $('#form_map_location').val();
                console.log(location);
        });

</script>
Start here and then work forward, testing with each piece.

Comment: Had to split up my answer into a few comments.  First time posting to this, I have received a lot of help from the users on Stack Overflow so just trying to return the favor.  Hopefully you get things resolved.