# Inline create input:color and click()

Tags: javascript, color-picker

It appear chrome has a bug with `<input type="color">`

This code works : (with a file input)

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'file';
    input.click();
```

But this code not : (with a color input)

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'color';
    input.click();
```

Why ? :-(

To test the code, you can open the console browser and paste the code.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can paste error here? because i don't see error when try with jsfiddle

Comment: it does not error in fact, it just no reaction

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var input = document.createElement('input');
  
input.setAttribute("type", "color");
document.body.appendChild(input);

input.addEventListener("click", onColorBoxClick); 

function onColorBoxClick(){
console.log('onclick');
}
```

Comment: if you add `input.click()` on the same snippet it does not work. if you do it at a later time it does

Answer (score 1):

you just create it in a variable and must append it to body.
so at the end must write this:

```
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on latest chrome edge an firefox

Only firefox is able to open the modal **from the console**
Chrome and Edge do nothing

So this is some kind of bug/feature

Comment: I had the same conclusion :-)

Answer (score 0):

Soluced !

For color input it need to add the input into the dom.
In my context (angular) I had need to add a second code line for fix the insert into dom delay like this :

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'color';
    input.style.opacity = 0;

document.body.appendChild(input);

$timeout(function() {
    input.click();
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a security risk to do this, so i think it will not available in all browsers, supposedly IE does allow it, but Mozilla and Opera do not.

Check this answer:

[In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)