# How to set width of input type "file" through css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

if you click just below `demonstration` word then also the **input type file** will click.

how to avoid that , so click event fire only on that area whatever size i have given .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
input{
border:3px solid red;
width:10px;
}
</style>
<h3>A demonstration of how to access a File Upload Button</h3>

<input type="file" id="myFile">

</body>
</html>
```

answer won't acceptable if you will wrap this **input type file**  with another element like label , div for security reason.  is it possible then ?

Comment: What is the "security reason" for not wrapping `<input type="file">` within an element?

Comment: @guest271314 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

Comment: @Mali How is linked Question related to a "security reason" for not wrapping an `<input type="file">` within an element?

Comment: because they will make another element and they will try to fire an event from that new element . so for input type file  click event doesn't work if you click using javascript not manually .

Comment: Still not following "security reason"? Can you link to the specific information that you are referencing at linked Question? If the event is `trusted` that event can be used to dispatch `click` event at `<input type="file">` from another element event handler, whether or not the `<input type="file">` element is a child element of that element.

Comment: @guest271314 by wrapping into another element (x). they will hide original element and will display x . and by click on x they will fire an event on original event . so it is won't acceptable right.

Comment: @Mahl _"by wrapping into another element (x). they will hide original element and will display x . and by click on x they will fire an event on original event ."_ The element `<input type="file">` element can be set to `display:none`, though it is not clear how that is related to a "security reason"? The same process described is possible where `<input type="file">` element is not the child element of the clicked element and the event at the element handler is `trusted`. That is, dispatching `click` event to `<input type="file">` element is not exclusive to the parent element.

Comment: @guest271314 my meant was that i won't accept answer if you create wrapper element for click event only.    yes you can use any number of ancestor of `input type file`  but that shouldn't involved in any click event.

Comment: _"my meant was that i won't accept answer if you create wrapper element for click event only. yes you can use any number of ancestor of `input type file` but that shouldn't involved in any click event."_ Your  acceptance of an answer is not the topic of the present communication. Rather, am attempting to substantiate and verify in which specific manner  `<input type="file">` being wrapped in an element is related to a  "security reason"? What is the specific "security reason"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
input{
border:3px solid red;
width:10px;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
<h3>A demonstration of how to access a File Upload Button</h3>

<input type="file" id="myFile">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DreamHunter I posted first. you can see.

Comment: sorry, my mistaken