# html - input file type trigger url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button for `upload image` in `html`:

```
<input id="album-image-input" style="display:none;" type="file" name="albumimages" multiple  onchange="previewImages(this.files)"  maxlength="10" accept="image/png,image/jpg"/>
<button  onclick="HandleBrowseClick('album-image-input');" >UPLOAD IMAGE</button>
```

with `js`:

```
function HandleBrowseClick(input_image){
    var fileinput = document.getElementById(input_image);
    fileinput.click();
}
```

At certain pages when I click on the `UPLOAD IMAGE`, it will call:

> Navigated to http://localhost:8888/mysite/?albumimages=

but not at some pages.

Why is that? And how can I prevent that from happen?

Comment: What's this go to: `onchange="previewImages(this.files)"`? We don't have all your code.

Comment: That button element would likely go to another page if it was in a form element. Take it out of the form, or add `type="button"` to the `<button>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security concerns, you generally aren't allowed to programmatically `click` an `input[type=file]` button.  In some cases, depending on if the button is visible, you may be allowed.  Yours is unlikely to work because the button is hidden.  For more information, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input).