# Auto click button on page load svg

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a script auto click on video icon button on page loading, but auto click is not working.

Code:

```
  <svg class="button" id="play-button">
  <use xlink:href="#play-button-shape">
 </svg>
```

Auto click script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("#play-button-shape").click();
</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the term "auto click".

Comment: where is `#play-button-shape` button in your code? And what does it do when clicked?

Comment: when i click '#play-button-shape' button, its play video.

Comment: here is a button bro, http://i.imgur.com/C2H1M8E.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)

Comment: not helpful....thanks for comment

Answer (score 1):

Try the `.on("click")` or `.trigger("click")` function, it does the same thing but I had pretty much the same case as you and it had unlocked me. 
I'm not sure it works but it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to "autoclick" on page load? Just use a `<video>` element with `autoplay`...

```html
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://mirror.cessen.com/blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: because my videos is youtube video

Comment: You can also autoplay YouTube videos in `<iframe>` if you add `autoplay=1` in the URL...

Comment: i know but i wants to autoplay on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("play-button").click();
}
```