# Fire Button Event on another onchange event in another button control

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, events

I'm trying to fire button click event from another button onchange event. but I got below error after event fired and no button event are NOT working, Below is my code, Can anyone please help me.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('btnPropertyUpload').addEventListener('click', openDialog);

  function openDialog() {
    console.log("funOnchange");
    document.getElementById('imgPropertyUpload').click();
  }

  function funOnchange() {
    $('#btnPropertySubmit').click();
  }
</script>

<div align="left">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("PropertyMaster", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    <span style="padding:5px 0px 0px 30px;">
      @Html.Label("lblPropPhotos", "PROPERTY PHOTOS")
    </span>
    <button type="button" id="btnPropertyUpload" class="btn-link">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload col-sm-2"></span>
    </button>
    <input type="file" id="imgPropertyUpload" style="display:none" name="postedFiles" multiple="multiple" onchange="funOnchange();" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="btnPropertySubmit" style="display:none" />
    <br /> 
    if (Model != null && Model.PropDetails.PropertyImages != null) 
    { 
      foreach (var image in Model.PropDetails.PropertyImages) {
        <img src="@Url.Content(image)" style="width:100px;height:100px; padding:5px 0px 0px 30px;" /> 
      } 
    } 
  }
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error, can you please post it? Also, why you are calling button click inside another button click?

Comment: See this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

Answer (score 0):

Try this - imgPropertyUpload is file input, so instead of click try focus and you can use jquery for all coding

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnPropertyUpload').on('click', function(){openDialog()});
});

  function openDialog() {
    console.log("funOnchange");
    $('#imgPropertyUpload').focus();
  }

  function funOnchange() {
    $('#btnPropertySubmit').click();
  }
```