# Trigger form file bootstrap vue with button

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

Hi i have a problem about triggering component b-form-file.

```
<b-form-file ref="imageProfile"></b-form-file>
```

I try with this.$refs.imageProfile.click() not work. And i see not found click function on that element.

Thank You.

Comment: Your `imageProfile` ref is a Vue component, not a standard element. It has no `click` method

Comment: What are you hoping to happen by calling `click()`?

Comment: I want to open dalog file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)

Comment: I wrote a slightly more detailed answer how to use <b-form-file> here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68959062/4720160

Answer (score 10):

The file form component of bootstrap-vue is a little different, for someone still get this problem, try this:

```
<b-form-file ref="pickImage" v-model="file" :state="Boolean(file)"></b-form-file>

this.$refs.pickImage.$el.childNodes[0].click();
```

hope this help !

Answer (score 6):

You need to trigger the click on the element, not the component.

Try this:

```js
this.$refs.imageProfile.$el.click()
```

See Vue Docs at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el