# Triggering a click() on a child component's file input won't work from a subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

Consider a component of which the template include a file input. The input can be opened by calling a public `open()` method which triggers a click on the `nativeElement` of the input.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<input type="file" #input/>',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @ViewChild('input')
  public input: ElementRef;

  public open(): void {
    console.log('OPENING THE FILE INPUT');
    this.input.nativeElement.click();
  }
}
```

This `ChildComponent` is called in a `ParentCompenent`, which calls `ChildComponent.open()` in multiple contexts, as defined below :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: '<child></child>',
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent)
  public child: ChildComponent;

  constructor( private parentService: ParentService ) {
  }

  public openChildInput(): void {
    // This works.
    // Output:
    //  OPENING THE FILE INPUT
    //  The file input opens

    this.child.open();
  }

  public waitAndOpenChildInput(): void {
    parentService.wait()
      .subscribe( () => {
        // This does not work.
        // Output:
        //  "OPENING THE FILE INPUT"
        //  The file input DOES NOT open...
        this.child.open();
      })
  }
}
```

In both cases, calling the `open()` method seems to work (as the `console.log` does show); yet the file input seems unwilling to open itself when called from a subscription.

Any ideas why ? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: Does it work if you do `setTimeout(()=>this.child.open(),0)` instead?

Comment: we need to see the service too so as @ConnorsFan said it would be nice to have a stackblitz

Comment: please paste the relevant content of `ParentService`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, it is not possible in modern browsers to programatically invoke the `click` event on a file input - **UNLESS** it happens during a *user interaction*. Otherwise, websites and ads could spam users with file dialoges without them interacting with the page and e.g. have them unknowingly upload a file.

The issue with using an Observable is that, if it is asynchronous (i.e. when using the `async` scheduler), you leave the *user interaction* context and the browser will not open the file dialog.

You can solve this only by making your Observable synchronous (which, actually, almost all preset Observables are). If you have e.g. a HTTP request, this won't be possible and you have to [look for alternatives for opening the file dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input) (though I'm not sure if any of those would work in your setup).

[Here is an GitHub issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7028) that is similiar to your problem with an explanation:

> Therefore [due to the asynchronity], the click() call [...] is not triggered by a user-event, from Chrome's perspective, and consequently is ignored.

Comment: That I didn't know, thanks it was quite informative ! I guess I'll work around the app design in order for the file input call to be in the context of the clic event. Many thanks !