# How to show the upload file dialog on page load

Tags: primefaces

Using PF10 (in a JoinFaces project), I'd like the Upload File dialog for choosing a file to show up when the page loads (i.e., without waiting for the user to click on the `Choose` button of `<p:fileUpload/>`). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use client side API `show()` function for this. But it seems more and more browsers are blocking triggering a click by script on an `input type="file"`. See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7772

You could take your chances and try to hijack a mouse move event to trigger a click on the upload input, which is answered on this question: [In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input) But I don't really like that hack.

Comment: I've just tried the following
```<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {PF('myUpload').show();});</script>```
Nothing happens, but the console shows "File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation." I guess this means this is not possible?

Comment: @mossaab what browser are you using?  He mentioned above Firefox seems to have an issue but Chrome does not.

Comment: @Melloware I tried on Chrome Version 92.0.4515.159.

Comment: Thanks @JasperdeVries! I'm accepting "not possible" as an answer.